# Using width and height from imagemagick identify

Tags: bash, ubuntu, imagemagick

I have learned that I can get the width and height of an image using:
identify image
How do I extract the width and height from the result of identify and store it in a variable ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set shell variables `width` and `height` to the width and height of an image, use:

```
width=$(identify -format '%w' "$filename")
height=$(identify -format '%h' "$filename")
```

#### Doing arithmetic on bash variables

The variables width and height can be manipulated using all the standard bash arithmetic operations.  For example:

```
$ width=$(identify -format '%w' "$filename")
$ echo "w=$width  2*w=$((2*width))  5+3*w=$((5+3*width))"
w=400  2*w=800  5+3*w=1205
```

Comment: @Hamza `width` and `height` can be used as integer values.  I added an example showing how to perform integer arithmetic on them.

Comment: `@Hamza` Width and Height from an image are already integers. What do you want to do with the Width and Height? If you give us more information, we can be more informative of what to do.

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you all !! I wanted to use it as a condition I found the answer:          if [ $((h)) -le 78 ]

Comment: `@Hamza`. Condition to do what? There may be easier ways depending upon what you are trying to do and also depending upon your ImageMagick version.